# Ensure spawned child process is killed if parent hits JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, child-process

In my next.js custom server.js file, I use child_process.spawn to start up a secondary server. I need this server to terminate if the main process is killed.

```
app.prepare().then(() => {
    // ... snip ...
    hardhatNetworkProcess = spawn('pnpm exec hardhat node', { shell: true, stdio: 'inherit' });
    // ... snip ...
    [
        'SIGHUP',
        'SIGINT',
        'SIGQUIT',
        'SIGILL',
        'SIGTRAP',
        'SIGABRT',
        'SIGBUS',
        'SIGFPE',
        'SIGUSR1',
        'SIGSEGV',
        'SIGUSR2',
        'SIGTERM',
    ].forEach((shutdownSignalType) => {
        process.on(shutdownSignalType, () => {
            hardhatNetworkProcess.kill();
        });
    });
});
```

Under normal exit conditions, this works, e.g. I can hit CTRL+C and both Next.js and the Hardhat server close.

However, occasionally NextJs gets a fatal error due to running out of memory. I believe this is a SIGABRT, and while SIGKILL is listed as unsupported for `process.on`, it doesn't say SIGABRT is unsupported.

I tried changing `hardhatNetworkProcess.kill()` to `hardhatNetworkProcess.kill('SIGKILL')`, and when that didn't work, I added `{ killSignal: 'SIGKILL' }` to the `spawn` call. This also didn't work. I've also tried permutations of the above without manually trying to kill it, and it seems the Hardhat server remains up and listening.

I've only seen this happen when the heap is out of memory, but given that seems to happen every once in a while when doing Next.js dev, I really don't want to have to manually look up the PID and kill it if this happens.

Is there a way to make sure the child process exits in this case? Or is my only option to do something heavier, like start a new process for both NextJs and Hardhat servers, so that I can monitor and kill via the "starter" process?

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[31779:0x75bac90]  1337758 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 2032.3 (2068.6) -> 2031.3 (2068.6) MB, 2.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.175, current mu = 0.089) allocation failure;
[31779:0x75bac90]  1337763 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 2032.3 (2068.6) -> 2031.3 (2068.6) MB, 2.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.175, current mu = 0.089) allocation failure;
[31779:0x75bac90]  1337774 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 2034.1 (2070.5) -> 2033.1 (2070.5) MB, 2.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.175, current mu = 0.089) allocation failure;


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb7a940 node::Abort() [next-router-worker]
 2: 0xa8e823  [next-router-worker]
 3: 0xd5c990 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [next-router-worker]
 4: 0xd5cd37 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [next-router-worker]
 5: 0xf3a435  [next-router-worker]
 6: 0xf3b338 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [next-router-worker]
 7: 0xf4b843  [next-router-worker]
 8: 0xf4c6b8 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [next-router-worker]
 9: 0xf2701e v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [next-router-worker]
10: 0xf283e7 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [next-router-worker]
11: 0xf08930 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [next-router-worker]
12: 0xeffefc v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawArray(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [next-router-worker]
13: 0xf00075 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Oddball>, v8::internal::AllocationType) [next-router-worker]
14: 0x11bafbe v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap> v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap, 2>::Allocate<v8::internal::Isolate>(v8::internal::Isolate*, int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [next-router-worker]
15: 0x11bb073 v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap> v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap, 2>::Rehash<v8::internal::Isolate>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap>, int) [next-router-worker]
16: 0x12c53bd v8::internal::Runtime_MapGrow(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [next-router-worker]
17: 0x16fb6f9  [next-router-worker]
Aborted
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 134.
```